# How to identify a unique identifier of a duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have duplicate records in a table. I need to be able to identify only one unique identifier so I can delete it from the table.

The only way I know there are a duplicate is from columns `subject` and `description` so if there are at least 2 of the same subject and the same description, I need to delete one and leave one.

So I was able to get a list of the duplicate records but I am not able to get the unique identifier to be able to delete it.

This is what I have done to identify the duplicate records.

```
SELECT 
    p.accountid, p.subject, p.description, count(*) AS total
FROM
    activities AS p 
WHERE     
    (p.StateCode = 1) AND p.createdon >= getdate()-6
GROUP BY 
    p.accountid, p.subject, p.description
HAVING 
    count(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    p.accountid
```

There is a column `record_id` which holds the unique identifier for each record. But if I added `record_id` to my select statement then I get no results because it is impossible to have a duplicate unique identifiers

How can I get the `record_id` using SQL Server?

**NOTE: the record_id is not an integer it is something like "D32B275B-0B2F-4FF6-8089-00000FDA9E8E"**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One nice feature that I like about SQL Server is the use of CTEs with `update` and `delete` statements.

You are looking for duplicate records and presumably want to keep either the lowest or highest `record_id`.  You can get the count and the id to keep using a CTE and window functions:

```
with todelete as (
    SELECT p.accountid, p.subject, p.description,
           COUNT(*) over (partition by p.accountid, p.subject, p.description) as total,
           MIN(record_id) over (partition by p.accountid, p.subject, p.description) as IdToKeep
    FROM activities AS p 
    WHERE (p.StateCode = 1) AND p.createdon >= getdate()-6
   )
delete from todelete
    where total > 1 and record_id <> IdToKeep;
```

The final `where` clause just uses the logic to select the right rows to delete.

I should add, if you just want the list that would be deleted, you can use the similar query:

```
with todelete as (
    SELECT p.accountid, p.subject, p.description,
           COUNT(*) over (partition by p.accountid, p.subject, p.description) as total,
           MIN(record_id) over (partition by p.accountid, p.subject, p.description) as IdToKeep
    FROM activities AS p 
    WHERE (p.StateCode = 1) AND p.createdon >= getdate()-6
   )
select *
from todelete
 where total > 1 and record_id <> IdToKeep;
```

The `over` function indicates that a function is being used as a window function.  This idea is simple.  `Count(*) over` returns the count for all records with the same values for the fields in the `partition` clause.  It is a lot like the aggregation function, except you get the value on every row.  This class of functions is quite powerful, and I'd recommend that you learn more about them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the record_id is not an integer it is something like this "D32B275B-0B2F-4FF6-8089-00000FDA9E8E"  I get this error with the second code Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for min operator.

Comment: @Mike . . . In that case, you can use `MIN(cast(record_id as varchar(255))) over . . .`.  The `MIN()` will return an arbitrary value to keep.  Is that a problem?  If so, how would you choose which of the record ids to keep?

Comment: Thank you so much that worked  but can you please explain to me what over and partition by doing?  Thanks

Comment: The over is creating a window so there can be multiple counts. The partition is telling it what to group by for each count. You can also include an order by inside the over for other scenarios like row_number from my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT max(p.record_id), p.accountid, p.subject, p.description, count(*) AS total
FROM activities AS p 
WHERE (p.StateCode = 1) AND p.createdon >= getdate()-6
GROUP BY p.accountid, p.subject, p.description
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY p.accountid
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you need to do an inner query first, then join against the larger table to get what you want.

```
SELECT ALL
    *
FROM (SELECT p.accountid
  FROM activities AS p
  WHERE p.statecode = 1 AND p.createdon >= getdate()-6
  GROUP BY p.accountid
  HAVING count(*) > 1) AS x
JOIN activities AS a ON x.accountid = a.accountid
ORDER BY p.accountid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with recordsToDelete as (
SELECT 
     recordId
    ,Row_Number() OVER(partition p.subject, p.description) as rowNum
FROM activities AS p 
)

select
*
from recordsToDelete
where rowNum > 1
```

If that looks correct, you can replace the select with:

```
delete from recordsToDelete
    where rowNum > 1
```